# How to test empty data in json file with angular

Tags: json, angularjs

I want to test if data are empty in a json file with angular.

here is my controller :

```
app.controller('infosVillageController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.infosvillages = [
    {
        "name":"Soleil camp (Le)",
        "id":1,
        "website":"",
        "email":""
    },
    {
        "name":"Camp Cosse (La)",
        "id":80,
        "website":"",
        "email":""
    }
];
}]);
```

As you see, sometimes i don't have datas in th json.

In my html i want to show if the datas are emptys. For exemple, i want to show "no website" or "no email".

So, how i can test if somme datas are empty in my json file ?

i have try something like this in my controller but it doesnt work :

```
    if ($scope.infosvillages.website == null) {
        $scope.infosvillages.website = "no website"
    };
```

thank you by advance

Comment: The code you posted doesn't load from a .json file.

Comment: Why not compare against empty string `""` instead of `null`

Comment: @WayneEllery sorry the json is in the controller

Comment: @RahilWazir i add this test too

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$scope.infosvillages.some(function(entry, i) {
    for(prop in entry){
        if(entry[prop] !== ""){
            console.log(entry[prop]);
            // or in your example
            entry[prop] = "no data found";
        }
    }
});
```

But to do what you want to do, I believe all you'd have to do is something like this:

```
if ($scope.infosvillages.website === "") {
        $scope.infosvillages.website = "no website"
    };
```